# ApplicationContextAware with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring

I'm trying to use ApplicationContextAware in my code with this help:
https://jerlinworld.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/making-your-spring-application-context-aware/

but is returning an exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.test.service.RoleService] is defined

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml, classpath:spring/web-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

business-config.xml:

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.example.test.extension.spring.ServiceLocator" />

<beans profile="allcomponents">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test" />
</beans>
```

My WebBean (exception is here):

```
try {
        ServiceLocator.getBean(RoleService.class).save(role);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ServiceLocator.java:

```
public class ServiceLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
        return ctx.getBean(clazz);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> clazz) {
        return ctx.getBean(beanName, clazz);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        // Assign the ApplicationContext into a static method
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key) {
        return ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

RoleService:

```
public interface RoleService {

    Role save(Role role);
}
```

RoleServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Role save(Role role) {
        return this.roleRepository.save(role);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The full stack trace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.examle.test.service.RoleService] is defined
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
>           at com.example.test.extension.spring.ServiceLocator.getBean(ServiceLocator.java:11)
>           at com.example.test.web.IndexWebBean.getTest(IndexWebBean.java:30)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
>           at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>           at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>           at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>           at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>           at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
>           at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
>           at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
>           at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

And in my business-config.xml:

```
<beans profile="allcomponents">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.make3.mymed" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  Is `RoleServiceImpl` in the appropriately component scanned package?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate proxying setup for `@Transactional`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes,  
<!-- enables scanning for Transactional annotations -->
 <tx:annotation-driven />

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/BkBGrypq

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

I was trying:

```
<beans profile="allcomponents">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.make3.mymed" />
</beans>
```

but when I moved to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.make3.mymed" />
```

worked!

why? I can't use this?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.make3.mymed" />
```

Comment: New questions in new questions please